# Как правильно указать ссылку?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Всем привет! При запуске моего проекта, изначальная его ссылка localhost:3000
Как можно сделать, чтобы только именно по ней показывался компонент?
Сейчас код выглядит так, и компонент показывается для любых символов после localhost:3000/

```
<Route path="/" component={Home} />
```

Вопрос очень дурацкий, но буду очень благодарен за помощь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно указать `exact`, то есть:

```js
<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
```

Из [документации](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/exact-bool):

> exact: bool
> При значении true будет выполняться только в том случае, если путь точно совпадает с location.pathname.

| path | location.pathname | exact | соответствует? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| /one | /one/two | true | нет |
| /one | /one/two | false | да |